# JS: Extend request body data while uploading a file

Tags: javascript

Consider this snippet:

```
fetch(encodeURI(insertObjectUrl), {
    method: 'POST',
    body: input.files[0]
})
```

Written in this way, the request body includes:

- File content
- File size
- File content type
- etc.

However, I would like to add also additional information, for instance manually providing a contentDisposition value (see [Object: insert](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert)).

How can I modify the code above to extend the request body?

I.e.

```
body: {
    'file': input.files[0];
    'contentDisposition: 'myvalue'
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData should help with this

Comment: Actually I never managed to properly upload a file with FormData. The file itself always contains `webkit-etc.`values.

Comment: That sounds like your server doesn't cope with multipart/formdata request bodies.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: JSON.stringify(data), 
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
}).then(res => res.json())
```

Based on this you can only pass data via the body. That being said you can add the contentDisposition (key,value) into the body as follows:

```
jsonData = {
    'file': input.files[0];
    'contentDisposition: 'myvalue'
}
```

Then in your request:

```
fetch(encodeURI(insertObjectUrl), {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
})
```

On the server you will need to convert the 'stringified' JSON data into object (using JSON.loads or another function).

Hope this helps